# Prove that the symmetric group $S_7$ is not generated by two 2-cycles.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Here is my idea for the proof.

Suppose $\sigma=(ab)$ and $\tau=(cd)$ are the two 2-cycles.

Suppose $S_7=<\tau,\sigma>$.

If $\tau$ and $\sigma$ are disjoint cycles, then they commute. From this we can conclude that if $\alpha\in <\tau,\sigma>$, then $\alpha$ has at most order 2.

So suppose WLOG $b=d$. So $\sigma=(ab)$ and $\tau=(cb)$

This gives me the impression that if $f\in\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ is not equal to $a$,$b$, or $c$, then for any permutation $\sigma(e)=e$.

Maybe I didn't even need the first half of this argument.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you make this conclusion?

Comment: You definitely don't need the first half of the argument.

Comment: @DonThousand This is not true at all. Two elements of order $2$ can generate a large dihedral group, even an infinite group. In this problem, we have to use the fact that they are transpositions (and even then, they can generate a group of order $6$, consider $(1,2)$ and $(2,3)$ which generate $S_3$).

Comment: @DonThousand $\langle a,b | a^2, b^2\rangle$ is infinite, but is generated by two elements of order 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you didn't need the first half of the argument. There are at most $4$ elements that are permuted by either of the generators. Thus only these at most $4$ elements are permuted by their products. $S_7$ contains permutations that permute the other at least $3$ elements, and these permutations aren't generated.

Comment: Since in general we don't know whether the two $2$-cycles have disjoint supports, shouldn't we say "...$4$ elements, or less, ..."? E.g., the products of $\sigma=(1,2)$ and $\tau=(2,3)$ permute just $1,2,3$. Of course your conclusion keeps correct (if not even reinforced).

Comment: @Luca: Yes, you're right; I've edited the answer accordingly.